# How to map 1 and 0 of a data frame as certain character in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a data frame involved 0 and 1, only the first column are characters:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 Col1 = c("0", "0", "0", "1"),
                 Col2 = c("0", "1", "1", "0"),
                 Col3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0"))
```

I wanna map the 1 to the character in the first column, and use `NA` to replace 0 in data frame, here is the data frame that I wanna have finally:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 Col1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "D"),
                 Col2 = c(NA, NA, "C", NA),
                 Col3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 3):

In `dplyr` you can `mutate` `across` all the columns that `matches` a certain pattern, and use an `ifelse` clause to map the `ID`values to the respective columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("Col"), ~ifelse(. == 1, ID, NA)))
  ID Col1 Col2 Col3
1  A <NA> <NA>   NA
2  B <NA>    B   NA
3  C <NA>    C   NA
4  D    D <NA>   NA
```

Comment: (+1) As you're going the `dplyr` route, it might be better to use typesafe `dplyr::if_else(. == 1, ID, NA_character_)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse()` in `base`:

```r
df[-1] <- ifelse(df[-1] == 1, df$ID, NA)

df
#   ID Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1  A <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2  B <NA>    B <NA>
# 3  C <NA>    C <NA>
# 4  D    D <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` approach with `case_match`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 or above needed
df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("Col"), ~ case_match(.x, "1" ~ ID)))
```